# How to convert a JOptionPane to a JDialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jdialog

I need to convert a JOptionPage to a JDialog, because I need to get rid of that quirky "OK" button. Below is the code...

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Interface, caption, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, icon);
```

Interface is my GUI, "caption" is the title, then I have a warning message, then I have my custom icon.

This might not even be possible with the given info, but I really need to get rid of that OK. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply create a JDialog without going through the JOptionPane step?

Comment: Well I've already coded the entire JOptionPane. I'm not sure if the only way to do this is to go back and recreate the entire code in a JDialog format, but if I didn't have to that'd be great.

Comment: `"Well I've already coded the entire JOptionPane..."` -- hell, that's one maybe two lines of code at most. I stand behind my same recommendation.

Comment: If Interface (which should be named interface) is a JPanel, then simply put it in your JDialog's contentPane. No need to create a class that extends JDialog. Just put your JPanel into one.

Comment: Haha ok perhaps I worded that wrong. Obviously JOptionPane is small, but to do a JDialog I'd have to create a Window and more stuff. The GUI is already created, and I can simply import that into the JOptionPane. Can't do that for a JDialog I believe.

Comment: Correct answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply create a JDialog and put your interface object into its contentPane, then pack it and display it. Simple.

---

You state:

> Obviously JOptionPane is small, but to do a JDialog I'd have to create a Window and more stuff. The GUI is already created, and I can simply import that into the JOptionPane. Can't do that for a JDialog I believe.

I'm confused. What do you mean by "the GUI"? Again, if it is a JPanel, again, simply put it into your JDialog.

For instance if in an ActionListener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  // assuming this is being called from within a JFrame named myFrame
  JDialog dialog = new JDialog(myFrame, "Dialog Title", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
  dialog.getContentPane().add(interface);
  dialog.pack();
  dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(myFrame);
  dialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

---

Another option is to use the JOptionPane constructor, and create it without showing it, and then convert it to a JDialog as the JOptionPane API shows you how to do, but you may still have the OK or similar button to deal with.

Comment: Alright let me test that out, and I'll see what comes out of it.

Comment: Alright, that did it! I was confused because of visibility settings. JOptionPane doesn't have to be set to true. 

Thanks a ton, I'll accept your answer in a moment when I'm able to. :)

Comment: @user3010468: yes you could use the JOptionPane constructor and create it without showing it, and then convert it to a JDialog as the JOptionPane API shows you how to do, but you may still have the OK or similar button to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Sure to Quit?", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

JDialog exitDialog = optionPane.createDialog(this, "Quit Confirmation");

exitDialog.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32192232)

Comment: There's no need to explain this `createDialog` is a bit obvious. I don't want to waste my time on something that is redundant. ;)