# How can I make a JRadioButton have the focus in a popup form created by passing a method to showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, swing, focus, traversal

EDITED--SUPPLIED REQUIRED CLASS

EDIT#2--REQUIRED CLASS CAME FROM [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/FocusTraversalDemoProject/src/misc/FocusTraversalDemo.java) and thus shouldn't require debugging, although I did change `Vector` to `ArrayList`.

[image]

I created this popup (modal) form by using `showMessageDialog` and passing a method (`popup`) to the `Object message` parameter. I have added traversal policy, extended to allow cursor key movement of focus, which works great except as follows.

The only problem I can't solve is how to make the cursor keys work immediately. The 'OK' button initially has the focus and the only key that will move the focus is `TAB`. Once a `JRadioButton` has the focus, the cursor keys work great to move the focus.

```
// LOSE THIS!! import Main.MyFocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static java.awt.event.KeyEvent.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewMain {
  static JPanel pnlPopup;
  static MyFocusTraversalPolicy ftPolicy;
  static JRadioButton rbtAsShown    = new JRadioButton();
  static JRadioButton rbtRandomly   = new JRadioButton();
  static JRadioButton rbtUser       = new JRadioButton();
  static JLabel lblAvailableDefinitionMethod = new JLabel();

  private static int popup() {
    pnlPopup = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    ButtonGroup buttonGroup1  = new ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup1.add(rbtAsShown);
    rbtAsShown.setSelected(false);
    rbtRandomly.setSelected(true);
    rbtUser.setSelected(false);
    rbtAsShown.setText("As already shown above");

    rbtAsShown.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
        rbtAsShown.setSelected(true);
      }});

    rbtRandomly.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
        rbtRandomly.setSelected(true);
      }});

    rbtUser.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
        rbtUser.setSelected(true);
      }});

    rbtAsShown.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt){
        rbtRandomly.setSelected(false);
        rbtUser.setSelected(false);
      }});

    buttonGroup1.add(rbtRandomly);
    rbtRandomly.setText("Randomly");

    rbtRandomly.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt){
        rbtAsShown.setSelected(false);
        rbtUser.setSelected(false);
      }});

    buttonGroup1.add(rbtUser);
    rbtUser.setText("I'll type them");
    rbtUser.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt){
        rbtRandomly.setSelected(false);
        rbtAsShown.setSelected(false);
      }});

    lblAvailableDefinitionMethod.setText("How should 'Available letters' be defined?");
    rbtUser.setMnemonic(VK_I);
    rbtRandomly.setMnemonic(VK_R);
    rbtAsShown.setMnemonic(VK_A);
    pnlPopup.add(lblAvailableDefinitionMethod);
    pnlPopup.add(rbtRandomly);
    pnlPopup.add(rbtUser);
    pnlPopup.add(rbtAsShown);

    Set downKeys;
    downKeys = pnlPopup.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
    Set newDownKeys = new HashSet(downKeys);
    newDownKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0));
    pnlPopup.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newDownKeys);    

    Set upKeys;
    upKeys = pnlPopup.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
    Set newUpKeys = new HashSet(upKeys);
    newUpKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0));
    pnlPopup.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newUpKeys);    

    pnlPopup.setFocusTraversalPolicy(ftPolicy);
    rbtRandomly.requestFocusInWindow();
    pnlPopup.setFocusCycleRoot(true);

    return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                         pnlPopup, 
                                         "Define Available letters", 
                                         JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
                                         JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    if(popup() == -1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cancelled");
    else              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"OK");
  }
}
```

Here is class `MyFocusTraversalPolicy`. Sorry I forgot it.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy;
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MyFocusTraversalPolicy extends FocusTraversalPolicy
    {
        ArrayList<Component> order;  // class var 

        public MyFocusTraversalPolicy(ArrayList<Component> o) {
            this.order = new ArrayList<>            (o.size());
            this.order.addAll                       (o);
        }
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                                           Component aComponent)
        {
            int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
            return order.get(idx);
        }

        public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
                                            Component aComponent)
        {
            int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
            if (idx < 0) {
                idx = order.size() - 1;
            }
            return order.get(idx);
        }

        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(0);
        }

        public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(order.size());
        }

        public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(0);
        }
    }
```

I assume that `rbtRandomly.requestFocusInWindow();` doesn't give the focus to button `rbtRandomly` because of how `showOptionDialog` works.

What can I do so that the cursor keys move the cursor among the buttons as soon as the form pops up?

P.S.
I'm using popup form because I need the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons to confirm user selection or desire to not proceed. I want a popup form with buttons because otherwise the UI looks and feels cruddy.

[image]

Comment: One solution is to use `AncestorListener`. See [Dialog Focus](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/) by @camickr for an example.

Comment: @Aqua--THANK YOU. Had I only jumped right onto your link, I'd've been done in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I had already almost solved my problem when @Aqua commented with a link. It took a lot more work than it was work to do it "my way", so I intend to follow the link. Here's what worked to produce this window, with cursor keys moving the focus among the 3 buttons, and with the added bonus of having `Esc` and `Enter` perform `Cancel` and `OK` actions. It's also based on an Answer supplied by @HovercraftFullOfEels [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22899581/how-to-convert-a-joptionpane-to-a-jdialog), which suggests using a `JDialog` rather than `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`.

[image]

```
  static JDialog dialog = null;
  static boolean retval ;
  static MyFocusTraversalPolicy ftPolicy;
  static JRadioButton rbtAsShown    = new JRadioButton();
  static JRadioButton rbtRandomly   = new JRadioButton();
  static JRadioButton rbtUser       = new JRadioButton();

  private static boolean popup() {
    JLabel lblAvailableDefinitionMethod = new JLabel();
    KeyBoundButton btnOK;
    JPanel pnlPopup;
    ButtonGroup buttonGroup1  = new ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup1.add(rbtAsShown);
    rbtAsShown.setSelected(false);
    rbtRandomly.setSelected(false);
    rbtUser.setSelected(false);
    rbtAsShown.setText("As already shown above");

    rbtAsShown.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
        rbtAsShown.setSelected(true);
      }});

    rbtRandomly.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
        rbtRandomly.setSelected(true);
      }});

    rbtUser.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter(){
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
        rbtUser.setSelected(true);
      }});

    rbtAsShown.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt){
        rbtRandomly.setSelected(false);
        rbtUser.setSelected(false);
      }});

    buttonGroup1.add(rbtRandomly);
    rbtRandomly.setText("Randomly");

    rbtRandomly.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt){
        rbtAsShown.setSelected(false);
        rbtUser.setSelected(false);
      }});

    buttonGroup1.add(rbtUser);
    rbtUser.setText("I'll type them");
    rbtUser.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener(){
      public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt){
        rbtRandomly.setSelected(false);
        rbtAsShown.setSelected(false);
      }});

    lblAvailableDefinitionMethod.setText("How should 'Available letters' be defined?");
    rbtUser.setMnemonic(VK_I);
    rbtRandomly.setMnemonic(VK_R);
    rbtAsShown.setMnemonic(VK_A);

    btnOK = new KeyBoundButton("OK", VK_ENTER, 0){
      @Override public void action(ActionEvent e){
        retval = true;
        dialog.dispose();
      }};

    KeyBoundButton btnCancel = new KeyBoundButton("Cancel", VK_ESCAPE, 0){
      @Override public void action(ActionEvent e){
        retval = false;
        dialog.dispose();
      }};

    pnlPopup = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pnlPopup.add(lblAvailableDefinitionMethod, new GBConstraints(0,0));
    pnlPopup.add(rbtRandomly, new GBConstraints(0,1));
    pnlPopup.add(rbtUser,     new GBConstraints(0,2));
    pnlPopup.add(rbtAsShown,  new GBConstraints(0,3));
    pnlPopup.add(btnOK,       new GBConstraints(0,4).anchor(WEST));
    pnlPopup.add(btnCancel,   new GBConstraints(0,4).anchor(EAST));

    Set downKeys; 
    downKeys = pnlPopup.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
    Set newDownKeys = new HashSet(downKeys);
    newDownKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0));
    pnlPopup.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newDownKeys);    

    Set upKeys;
    upKeys = pnlPopup.getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
    Set newUpKeys = new HashSet(upKeys);
    newUpKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0));
    pnlPopup.setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.BACKWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, newUpKeys);    

    ArrayList<Component> order1 = new ArrayList<>(3);
      order1.add(rbtRandomly);
      order1.add(rbtUser);
      order1.add(rbtAsShown);
    ftPolicy = new MyFocusTraversalPolicy(order1);    
    pnlPopup.setFocusTraversalPolicy(ftPolicy);
    pnlPopup.setFocusCycleRoot(true);
    dialog = new JDialog(null, "Dialog Title", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    dialog.getContentPane().add(pnlPopup);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dialog.setVisible(true);    
    return retval && (rbtAsShown.isSelected() || rbtUser.isSelected() || rbtRandomly.isSelected());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    if(popup()){
      if(rbtAsShown.isSelected()) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"As shown");
      if(rbtRandomly.isSelected())JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Random");
      if(rbtUser.isSelected())    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User");
    }
    else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cancelled");
  }
```

Here's `KeyBoundButton`, which maps escape to cancel and enter to OK.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import static javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke;

public abstract class KeyBoundButton extends JButton{

  public abstract void action(ActionEvent e);

  public KeyBoundButton(String buttonText, char acc, int key, int mask){
    Action myAction = new AbstractAction()
    {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
        action(e);
      }
    };  

    setAction(myAction);
    setText(buttonText);
    setMnemonic(acc);
    getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                  .put(getKeyStroke(key, mask),buttonText);
    getActionMap().put(                        buttonText, myAction);

  }

  public KeyBoundButton(String buttonText, int key, int mask)
  {
    this(buttonText, buttonText.charAt(0), key, mask );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ELEGANT SOLUTION due to **camickr**.

**ALL THAT IS REQUIRED TO MODIFY THE ORIGINAL CODE IS:**

(a) Get class `RequestFocusListener` from [here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/03/14/dialog-focus/)

(b) Add **ONE LINE** of code: `rbtRandomly.addAncestorListener(new RequestFocusListener());`

camickr's explanation at the link above is great.